# How to find specific number from array?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some code here for finding only left first small number from an array.

```
public void Test() {
    int[] numbers = { 121, 124, 131, 135, 219, 287, 361, 367, 382, 420 };
    var onlyfirstNumbersLessThanGiven = numbers.TakeWhile(n => n < 135);
    Console.WriteLine("First numbers less than ");
    foreach (var n in onlyfirstNumbersLessThanGiven)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    } 
}
```

How to find only 131 from above array? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This example helps to clear.**

> public void Test()
>
> {
>
> int[] numbers = { 121, 324, 431, 135, 119, 287, 361, 367, 382, 420 };
>
> var OFNLTG = numbers.Where(x => x < 121).Max();
>   Console.WriteLine("First Max Number:");
>
> { 
>      Console.WriteLine(OFNLTG);
>
> }
>
> }

Comment: Why this is the accepted answer? This is exactly the solution I proposed

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

Ordered array:

```
numbers.LastOrDefault(x => x < 135);
```

Unordered array:

```
numbers.Where(x => x < 135).Max();
```

Answer (score 3):

Although Renan's answer is perfectly correct, why not just use First(), **edited** or TakeWhile() with Last()?

e.g.

```
int[] numbers = { 9, 34, 65, 92, 87, 435, 3, 54, 
                    83, 23, 87, 435, 67, 12, 19 };

int first = numbers.First(number => number > 80);
int firstSmaller = numbers.TakeWhile(number => number < 80).Last(); // returns 65 since its the first one smaller than 80 in the series

Console.WriteLine(first);
```

And to match it with your situation:

```
public void Test() {
    int[] numbers = { 121, 124, 131, 135, 219, 287, 361, 367, 382, 420 };
    var onlyfirstNumbersLessThanGiven = numbers.TakeWhile(n => n < 135).Last();
    Console.WriteLine("First numbers less than ");
    Console.WriteLine(onlyfirstNumbersLessThanGiven);
}
```

There are restrictions: the array is assumed to be sorted, and must be in ascending order.

Thanks to **Ivan Stoev** for pointing out my mistake

Comment: `First(n => n < 135)` in your example will return 121 while OP is expecting 131

Comment: Good Catch, I am modifying the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Find the number itself, since you know the number you want, you do not need any range.

```
numbers.Where(x => x == 131);
```